# Pandas how to convert 2 columns of dataframe to series?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

here, I would like to convert a 2 columns dataframe to New series.
'max' is suppose to be the index and 'price' is the value of the new Series.
how to do that ?
the way I used below seems incorrect:
pd.Series(a['max'], index=a['price'])

```
>>> a
      price  max
0       4.0   86
1       5.0   87
2       6.0   88
3       7.0   91
4       8.0   91
..      ...  ...
385  1900.0   98
386  2000.0   97
387  2013.0   91
388  2500.0   96
389  3300.0   88

[390 rows x 2 columns]
>>> type(a)
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do

```
s=df.set_index('max')['price']
```